# CSS Button Has a huge Left Indent

Tags: css, wordpress

So on my site, I was building out a graphical menu of buttons in 4 stacks. The problem is for some reason my one button when I tell it to float left decides to just indent itself to the left a huge amount not aligning with the other buttons above it. There is a link below:

http://www.bluestarnj.com/?page_id=49

I can post the css code if you guys want, but it's all accessible through either firebug or chrome developer. I also coded this button exactly as I did the other ones when I started a new line.

Baroti

Comment: Well you gave it a 15% margin left on line 702 of style.css

Comment: Try getting rid of the `float:left` on all of them and changing it to `display:inine-block`. The float does some funny things with layouts dependent on the height of all elements

Comment: Well I removed the margin, though that was on a button after the one causing an issue. I also changed everything to inline-block. I get the first 4 buttons to line up correctly but then after that they're all a mess except the last four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see issues with 2 buttons.

The first one, "Speciality Products Bulk", as David mention, has `margin-left: 15%;`

The second one, "Glass Cleaners", is dealing with elements above it having inconsistent heights. "Disinfectants-Bowl Cleaners", "Drain Maintainers/Openers", and "Finishes-Sealers" have heights of 42px. These heights make "Glass Cleaners" have what looks like a huge left margin.

Comment: ahh okay so basically I should make all the heights of the buttons the same for the css?

Comment: Yep, that would fix the second issue.

Comment: http://www.bluestarnj.com/?page_id=49 I set all the heights to 42px same issue, certain buttons just wont float to the left of others.

Comment: Actually it seems the way I was trying to automatically center the #store_menu div with
       width: 50%;
         margin: 0 auto;

was causing the issues

Comment: Some of your buttons don't have a float. "Finishes-Sealers" and "Handcleaners and Dispensers"

Comment: Looks like I about got it, thanks for all the suggestions guys, I guess what I'll just do is push the first button with a left indent to center it under the other three lines.

Comment: Stylistically, I would suggest moving the floats to the `li`, and having the parent  `ul` clearfix or `overflow: hidden;`.